# Similar statements for expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Is there an easy way to find out which 3 are similar from the left and right side, it will be nice with some tricks to find it out, or if you have some rules that can be followed.

$$
{lg\,n +\frac12} \qquad \qquad \frac {(n^2 + lg\,n)}n
$$
$$
\frac {n^2} 2 + n\, lg \,n \qquad \qquad n^{lg \,10}
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{lg \, n} 2^i \qquad \qquad \sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac12
$$
$$
100(4 + \frac1n) \qquad \qquad 5n(4 + 2^{lg\,n})
$$

ps.
i'm a noob at math

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "similar". I don't think any two of these 8 expressions are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re talking about rates of growth, $\sum_{i=1}^{100}\frac12=50$ is $\Theta(1)$, as is $100\left(4+\frac1n\right)$. Assuming that $\lg$ is the binary log, $n\le\sum_{i=1}^{\lg n}2^i\le 2n$ for $n\ge 1$, so $\sum_{i=1}^{\lg n}2^i$ is $\Theta(n)$, as is $\frac{n^2+\lg n}n=n+\frac{\lg n}n$. And $\frac{n^2}2+n\lg n$ is $\Theta(n^2)$, as is $5n(4+2^{\lg n})=5n(4+n)=5n^2+20n$. The unmatched functions are $\lg n+\frac12$, which is $\Theta(\lg n)$, and $n^{\lg 10}$, which is already the simplest function in its growth class, falling strictly between $\Theta(n^3)$ and $\Theta(n^4)$.